# Authentication in external application using Moodle

Tags: php, desktop-application, moodle

Moodle version 3.2

I have a desktop based application which is integrated with Moodle i.e. it uses users and their credentials created in Moodle.

Correct me if I m wrong. Password in Moodle is salted and then stored in database. And, this encryption is irreversible. So, how do I authenticate the users on my external application?

I assume, I'll have to redirect users to moodle's authentication API and then redirect them back to my application after successful or unsuccessful attempt.

Please help on how to go about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean use Moodle as an IDP?

Answer (score -1):

Moodle has an entire Authentication API for this purpose. Check this out https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_API

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i don't want to authenticate Moodle with external db. I want to authenticate external application with Moodle db.